# How can I assign JQuery click handlers via iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code which can be seen [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pdcdoajd/1/). The idea would be that I could have a list of items, which I could then assign a handler to run whatever repetitive code I would need to run (for example, a function which modifies a series of classes). The idea is that I could iterate through a list of ids and assign a handler, however due to my limited knowledge of Javascript, it doesn't' appear to be working. Would anyone be able to help?

**The Code of Interest:**

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="first">First</a><br>
<a href="#" id="second">Second</a><br>
<a href="#" id="third">Third</a><br>
<a href="#" id="forth">Forth</a><br>
```

**Javascript:**

```
//Choose which ids I want to iterate
ids = ['#first', '#second', '#third', 'forth']

//For all the ids there are
for ( i=0; i<ids.length; i++ ) {

    //Select an item
    item = ids[i]

    //Add a click handler to that item
    $( item ).click(function() {

          //Run a function that involves knowing the item I have iterated...
          alert( "Handler for "+ item + " called." );
    });
}
```

Thanks,
Aj.

Comment: Why would you need that? Why not using a common class?

Comment: First off, I'm with @A.Wolff, I don't think you'll need iteration.

Anyway, the element that the handler is attached to is available in a variable named "this" in your handler function

Comment: Because in my situation @A.Wolff I have a list of buttons, of which when I press one, it will make all the other buttons 'deactivated' and my selected class 'active' via changing applying classes. Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Like @ClaytonLeis said, then use `this` inside handler. Smells like an xy problem to me http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a need for a loop, but the problem you are experiencing is http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196. Since you didn't seem to be aware of `this`, I recommend to read the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as expected because you're assigning to a global item. Since, javascript has only globals and function locals, saying

```
var item = ids[ i ];
```

will not work either. You could jQuery's each method to iterate over your array:

```
$.each( ids, function( index, value ) {
  $( value ).click( function() { } );
} );
```

or, wrap your item in a function this way:

```
for( i=0; i<ids.length; i++ ) {
  (function(value) {
    $( value ).click(function() { });
  })( ids[i] )
}
```

you could also just do this

```
$( ids.join( ',' ) ).click( function(e) {
  // No variable "item" available here
  // access the target element by $(this) or $(e.target)
} );
```

Comment: I believe that `$.each()` example will result in each click event causing 4 alerts. Might want to throw it into a snippet to verify...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet with the bare minimum changes necessary to fix the two problems.

- Problem #1: Missing the `#` before `forth` in the `ids` array.
- Problem #2: Need to use `this` instead of `item` in the click handler.

```js
//Choose which ids I want to iterate
ids = ['#first', '#second', '#third', '#forth']

//For all the ids there are
for ( i=0; i<ids.length; i++ ) {

    //Select an item
    item = ids[i]

    //Add a click handler to that item
    $( item ).click(function() {

          //Run a function that involves knowing the item I have iterated...
          alert( "Handler for "+ this.id + " called." );
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="first">First</a><br>
<a href="#" id="second">Second</a><br>
<a href="#" id="third">Third</a><br>
<a href="#" id="forth">Forth</a><br>
```